# Does SQL Server allow moving backwards with standby file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup, restore

I have a database in `standby` mode.

```
-- STEP 1
-- Restore path F1 > T7
RESTORE DATABASE [TestRestore] FROM DISK = N'C:\Temp\F1.BAK' WITH FILE = 1, 
NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5
GO

-- STEP 1
RESTORE LOG [TestRestore] FROM DISK = N'C:\Temp\T7.TRN' WITH FILE = 1, 
STANDBY = N'C:\Temp\TestRestore_RollbackUndoFile.tuf', NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5
GO
```

And now I'm gonna do log shipping. My database is accessible(`read only`)so it will be easy to determine specific point in time where I need to stop at.

```
-- STEP 3
-- Restore T8
USE [master]
RESTORE LOG [TestRestore] FROM DISK = N'C:\Temp\T8.TRN' WITH FILE = 1, 
STANDBY = N'C:\Temp\TestRestore_RollbackUndoFile.tuf', 
NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, STOPAT = N'2013-10-25T19:55:26'
GO

-- STEP 4
-- ckecking
SELECT * FROM TestRestore.dbo.TranRecord
GO
```

I can perform the same transaction log restore repeatedly until I arrive at the required point-in-time by incrementing the time specified in the `STOPAT` clause.

But, for example, do I need to repat the whole restore again in case I've realized that I've restored too far ahead ?(I mean delete the current restored `db` and do restore `F1 > T7 > T8` again and stop at exactly where I need). Or it is possible to undo just the last log shipping ?(in my example it's `STEP 3`).

[Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) gives it pretty controversial connotation.

> Specifies a standby file that allows the recovery effects to be
>   undone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must restart the restore sequence.

I believe SQL Server could theoretically allow  moving backwards in time because the logs contain both undo and redo information. But this is either not implemented or it is not possible for some reason.

Comment: Thanks fro this info. I appreciate it. At least now I know. Msdn gives it pretty controversial connotation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Here you can see what the standby file contains. RESTORE WITH STANDBY essentially recovers the database fully but it copies unrecovered pages to the standby file. If you continue restoring those pages are copied back to undo the recovery that had taken place. So that file can only be used to move back in time to a very specific point.

Comment: `move back` I misunderstood it. In other words only one direction is possible, Right ?(when a restoring starts we are always going further - from past to future - even if it's standby restore)